# Calling a function from another class with Logos (%hook)

Tags: function, ios6, jailbreak, theos, logos

Note: *This code is not an exact replica of the original code, but illustrates (with good accuracy) what the issue is, and what my intentions with the code are.*

I have added a button to `DaClass1`'s view (*this works fine*):

```
%hook DaClass1

-(id)DaView {
    UIButton *xButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [xButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissWithAnimation:YES:nil)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [xButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/Hello.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    xButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [self addSubview:xButton];
    return %orig;
}

%end
```

But the `UIButton`'s `action:` (`dismissWithAnimation:YES:nil`) is actually from another class:

```
%hook DaClass2
    -(void)dismissWithAnimation:(int) reason:(int) {
        //someCodeHere...
    }
%end
```

How may I call `dismissWithAnimation` in `DaClass2` from my `UIButton`'s `action:` when the UIButton is in `DaClass1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `%new` function that calls `dismissWithAnimation` in `DaClass2`.

```
%hook DaClass1

//Your Code...

%new

-(void)dismissIt {
    [[%c(DaClass2) sharedInstance] dismissWithAnimation:YES:nil];
}

%end
```

and set the `xButton`'s `action:` to "`dismissIt`":

```
[xButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissIt) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the @selector(dismissWithAnimation:YES:nil) method is in the class DaClass2?

Then do:

```
[xButton addTarget:(instance of DaClass2) action:@selector(dismissWithAnimation:YES:nil) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: It has to be an INSTANCE of DaClass2 unless it's a class method.

Comment: Or hold a reference to an instance of DaClass2, declare a local button press handler method, and in that method, call your dismissWithAnimation method on that DaClass2 object.